# Locked out of administrator account and do not remember root password (password was manually set for root)

Tags: grub2, login, password, root

I was writing a script to help force myself to go to bed.  It had two parts, first, it would lock my account at 11PM using crontab.  Then, I added a unlock if statement that was supposed to unlock the account after 5AM.  Obviously the unlock script did not work, but that isn't the current question, just some background.

Normally, as many would suggest you would drop to root console from grub.  However, I cannot do this because I am still inexperienced in ubuntu and at some point I enabled the root account and set a password I do not remember for it.  Stupid, I know.  Is there any ways to unlock my account?